# Who are some affordable ($500/m) Magento Ready Website Hosting Providers?

Tags: magento-enterprise, price, migration, websites, hosting

Our IS Department has been tasked with finding a website hosting solution that is Magento ready. Our budget is approximately $500.00 monthly, enabling us to move away from all of our current hosting providers. We are hoping you can recommend some Magento ready website hosting providers.

Based on various discussions, our selection criteria are as follows:

Mandatory (Required)

- Magento Ready – the provider is aware of Magento, and has built their infrastructure in consideration of (or is compatible with) Magento requirements
- Fully Managed – the server will be kept up to date by the supplier (OS, third party applications, etc.) – but not Magento (version, updates, etc.)
- Dedicated Server(s) – the provider will provide us with dedicated server(s) that are not shared with other clients
- Secure Access – the OS and software need to be secure (SFTP, etc.)

Important

- NOC Center – department that assists in defending attacks and mitigating responses on behalf of their customers – also responsible for the maintenance and overall health of network and internal resources

Nice to have’s

- DDoS attack ready – be able to help mitigate DDoS attacks and other attack vectors
- Load Balanced – two or more servers that work together to offset heavy loads between them
- Redundancy – provisioning of failover server – sometimes located in a different geographica location
- Backups – able to regularly backup the website
- Magento Updates – supplier to automatically apply Magento updates as provided by Magento
- Servers are Geographically dispersed around the globe – enables sites to remain up in case of disasters and ensures high-availability in other countries

We have 7 websites and we wish for them all to share the same Magento installation. We estimate our requirements as follows:

- Hard drive space - 50-75GB
- Memory - 8GB
- Bandwidth - 1TB

Should we find that the expected requirements price ourselves above our approved price ceiling, or outpace the ability to have all installations on one server, then we may need to have more than one server provisioned.

According to paperwork offered by Magento, the following represents our Server Sizing (Peak):

```
Page views per day                 29,930
Page views per hour                5,000
Orders per day                     250
Orders per hour                    100
Concurrent Magento Admin Users     2
Concurrent Sessions                1
Concurrent requests per minute     1
```

We must accommodate an approximate growth factor of 30% per following years.  Magento will be provisioned to accommodate a single URL for all regions with different views for languages and currencies, and will be integrated with `NetSuite`, `Celigo`, `Payflow Pro`, `PayPal`, and `Avatax`.

Kindly provide us with a list of recommended website hosting providers that meet our criteria, or direct us to the correct place.

Comment: I think you may be reading that wrong, kab8609. It says 5k page views per hour and 250 orders per day.

Comment: At your size, I'd recommend a dedicated database server and a dedicated web server, and also add a CDN. However, it really makes sense to increase your budget to accommodate this. I'd recommend talking to a Magento hosting partner. Rackspace is great, but Nexcess is great and also more likely to be in your budget.

Comment: Thanks @tsHunter you were right. I saw it before it was edited. However, I am concerned about his "Magento Updates" nice to have. Makes me think they don't have an actual developer managing this.

Comment: @kab8609 I agree. I just wanted to make sure you could fix that part of it so that your other valid concerns were not overlooked by people writing it off because of the count inaccuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was in your shoes, I would recommend you contacting several Magento sponsored hosting providers.

Those providers can be found here:

http://partners.magento.com/partner_locator/search.aspx?f0=Types+of+Partners&f0v0=Hosting+Partner

For a budget of $500/month, you are looking at 1 server, however nearly everything in your list is standard.

I won't recommend one hosting provider over another, as this is mainly based on opinions. I have worked with Nexcess, Rackspace, Peer1, and have heard really great things about Sonassi Hosting. However, at the end of the day, you are the one that is going to have to fact check.

One thing I do want to caution is one of your nice to have

- Magento Updates – supplier to automatically apply Magento updates as provided by Magento

This should never be done by a hosting company, only by your developer that knows your code.

Comment: I would agree with the user above that said you should check out Nexcess. They really know their stuff and would be quite helpful in helping you get all this figured out